# How to place views vertically or horizontally in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Here is the Constraintlayout with 3 views:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_name"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_profile_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_headline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_name" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result:

[image]

As you can see, there is a big gap between each view. How can I remove those gaps and have them centered on the screen. I can achieve this easily using RelativeLayout or LinearLayout, but how can I do it in this ConstraintLayout? Is ConstraintLayout suppose to be a replacement for RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a view has two opposing constraints, `ConstraintLayout` will center the view between those constraints. This is what is happening in your layout.

If you want the views stacked one on top of another in the center of the screen, one way to do it is to used a [packed chain](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-chain).

Here is your layout using a vertical packed chain:

[image]

Here is the XML. Notice how the views are vertically constrained.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_name"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tv_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_headline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_profile_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_headline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tv_headline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_name" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

ConstraintLayouts are said to give a flatter view hierarchy and better performance than normal RelativeLayouts.

I see some things that might cause wierd behaviour. For example in this view:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_profile_image" />
```

You say that the top of this view should be aligned with the top of the @+id/iv_profile_image-view. Are you sure you don't mean that the top of this view should be aligned with the *bottom* of the @+id/iv_profile_image-view? And so on for the other views...

Answer (score 0):

## Try this it was helpful for you

- we,ve to used all four `constraints` like `left,right,top and bottom`
- you can implement like this also
- I don'nt think you always prefer `Drag and Drop` you may go with the programmatic approarch also

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_profile_image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_name"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_profile_image"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_headline" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_headline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_name" />

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

## Happy to help you